# Как самому создать авторизацию или переопределить User Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, auth

При изучении ASP.NET MVC встал вопрос авторизации. Запустил пример в студии - ничего не понял, что там делается на самом деле. Поиск в Google по *User Identity* не помог.

Цель: нужно создать доступ к контроллеру только у определённых ролей. Как ни странно, я не нашёл примера "делай так -> получай это".

Вопросы:

- Где идёт обращение к таблицам? Я увидел таблицы *AspNetUsers* и другие. Мне не нужно шифровать пароль (его должны видеть администраторы).
- Есть ли сайт, где показан процесс, как мне авторизоваться и переопределить поля таблицы или вообще изменить это ядро, "от А до Я"?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать Authorize фильтр.

его можно повесить на весь контроллер, и в свойстве Roles через запятую перечислить названия ролей, которым Вы даете доступ:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager")]
public class FileController : ApiController
{}
```

а можно повесить на отдельный метод контроллера:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager")]
    public ActionResult Method1()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```